# vuejs v2.0 pass data to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I built an app on Laravel 5.3 using vue.js and im starting to move over to vue.js to make the pages dynamic. I got everything working on a single page so want to convert that over to a component but after doing so I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <homepage> at C:\xampp\htdocs\....... 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nxt_weekly' of undefined
```

I was passing data to the view like so:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

mounted: function () {
    this.fetchEvents();
},

data: {
    loading: true,
    stats: []
},

methods: {
    fetchEvents: function () {
        this.$http.get('home/data').then(function (response) {
            this.stats = response.body;
            this.loading = false;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

});
```

In stats[] is where I hold the JSON response from the API and then call them all in my view like so:

```
<span class="stat" v-text="'stats.nxt_today'"></span>
....
....
```

This works but when I switch over to creating a component the errors listed above show, my new code is:

```
Vue.component('homepage', require('./components/Homepage.vue'),{

    mounted: function () {
        this.fetchEvents();
    },

    data: function () {
        return{
            loading: true,
            stats: []
        }
    },


    methods: {
        fetchEvents: function () {
            console.log('running here');
            this.$http.get('home/data').then(function (response) {
                this.stats = response.body;
                this.loading = false;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How come my stats[] object is now empty when the component is trying to access it?

Comment: Why does stats start as an Array then turn into an object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass your `stats` as a property to the component using `v-bind`, as shown below:

```
<homepage v-bind:stats="stats"></homepage>
```

The above needs to be done in your root template. And in your `homepage` component, you can receive the value in `props` as follows:

```
Vue.component('homepage', {
    props: ["stats"],
    mounted: function () {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
}
```

Within the template of this component, you will be able to access `stats.nxt_today` normally.

By the way, is your stats an array or an object? You have defined it as an empty array initially, but accessing it as an object.

If you still have issues, you can use [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to view all the objects available within a component.

Comment: So I have to make all my API queries in the new Vue instance and then pass each one into each separate component?

Comment: Ideally you should be using Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) to maintain a store for all the API queries. Vuex is like a database on the browser app. It maintains a complete state of all the data, while being fully accessible to all components (within that Vue instance only). So, you can have a simple check if the API data is available in Vuex state or not, and then make the actual API call if it is not already loaded.

Comment: But to answer your main question, yes - you can make the API queries in the parent component and pass it to child component via `props`. It is a one-way binding from parent to child. If you think Vuex is an overkill for your app, you can definitely do it this way.